# Information on runas command

Tags: cmd, runas, icacls

This question may be duplicate but since I didn't find any answer I am posting it here

1. My username has space in between; so how should I write it while using runas; should I use double quote or single quote or \

   e.g. runas /noprofile /user:mymachine-pc\john smith cmd

in above e.g john & smith have space in-between

1. My cmd contains path,double quote etc ; so how should I  pass whole thing as cmd to runas ; for e.g.

   cmd=icacls "C:\Users\Public\Public Desktop" /GRANT John smith:F /T

I want to run above command as

```
"runas /noprofile /user:mymachine-pc\john smith icacls "C:\Users\Public\Public Desktop" /GRANT John smith:F /T
```

Now above command has lot of problem ; I am really confused; john smith has admin right also; and I am trying to run this from batch file

Comment: Quotes go around the whole string so `runas /noprofile /user:"mymachine-pc\john smith" cmd` (I haven't checked anything other than your name). Icacls require colons so your command won't work with or without quotes. `runas /noprofile /user:"mymachine-pc\john smith" icacls "C:\Users\Public\Public Desktop" /GRANT:"John smith":F /T
`

Comment: @Noodles thanks for the help; I used use suggestion please see log below; though it didn't give error but my FILE PERMISSION DIDN'T CHANGE

Answer (score 2):

Try escaping inner quotes.

```
runas /noprofile /user:"mymachine-pc\john smith" "icacls \"C:\Users\Public\Public Desktop\" /GRANT \"John smith\":F /T"
```

Comment: C:\Users\john smith>runas /noprofile /user:"johnsmith-pc\john smith" "icacls \"C
:\ProgramData\setti
ngs_config.bin\" /GRANT \"john smith\":F /T"
Enter the password for johnsmith-pc\john smith:
Attempting to start icacls "C:\ProgramData\settings_config.bin" /GRANT "john smith":F /T as user "johnsmith-pc\john smith" ...

File PERMISSION DIDN'T CHANGE

Comment: COLON COLON COLON Read my comment

Comment: I used colon after GRANT: 
any other way than this gives error ...It seems everything after runas user:"mymachine-pc\john smith" should be in between double quote

Comment: Have you copied the command correctly? I see a space between C: in your comment ... "icacls \"C :\ProgramData ...

Comment: `C:\Users\David Candy>RunAs /user:Admistrator "icacls delstack.bat /grant \"David Candy\":F" this works`. Type just icacls on your object and paste here and let us see what is up.

Comment: that's not a space..i have rechecked...there is space in my path though...C:\ProgramData\some directory\settings_config.bin...I have double quoted my path to resolve it 
C:\Users\john smith>runas /noprofile /user:"johnsmith-pc\john smith" "icacls \"\
"C:\ProgramData\some path\set
tings_config.bin\"\" /GRANT:\"john smith\":F"
Enter the password for johnsmith-pc\john smith:
Attempting to start icacls ""C:\ProgramData\some path\settings_config.bin"" /GRANT:"john smith":F as user "johnsmith-pc\john smith" ...

Comment: I manual gave full permission to whole directory...so that even if new files get create/generated they have full permission by default...

Comment: One other thing I have noticed is that your are running icacls under john smith credential to give access to john smith. This cannot happen. If John Smith did not have access, he cannot grant access.

Comment: but john smith is part of administrator group and he can do it manually(via user interface)